# "Requested value 'APIObject' was not found." error with SOAP Create/Update Requests from WSDL

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, error-messages, wsdl

We have been working with integration tools that are very strict about the use of the Marketing Cloud WSDL "as is".

At the moment we are working on a mc.test.exacttarget.com account.

The issue is that when we use the WSDL here (https://webservice.test.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl) our requests do not include the xsi:type="" attribute on the  tag.

The concern here is that without the xsi:type="DataExtensionObject" (for example) we get an error for our calls for **Requested value 'APIObject' was not found.**

Is there a way to designate the APIObject in the structure provided from the WSDL? We see APIObject underneath 'Container' but have not been successful in creating a call that adds data.

Essentially: we need an alternative to declaring xsi:type="" if one exists. Hopefully through the WSDL structure itself.

---

**Example call that does not work. xsi:type="DataExtensionObject" not included on  tag which is what code.exacttarget.com includes in all of their examples. We generate this from the WSDL through an interface.**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>xxxxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yyyyy</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
        <SaveOptions>
            <SaveOption>
                <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
            </SaveOption>
        </SaveOptions>
    </Options>
    <Objects>
        <CustomerKey>invoice_example_table</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
            <Property><Name>PrimaryKey</Name><Value>Post1</Value></Property>
        </Properties>               
    </Objects>
</UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

Since the construction of the envelope does not provide a method for defining xsi:type="" inside the  tag, we are hoping there are other elements we can bring into the envelope from the WSDL where we can define APIObject as to not receive the error described.

Comment: Can you include an example SOAP request for the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for reaching out Daniel. I'll be making an edit here shortly to include.

Comment: Here is an example of the structure we can generate from the WSDL. The issue being that the xsi:type="DataExtensionObject" is missing from the OBJECTS tag. This is something that most examples from code.exacttarget.com include. However: it's puzzling that the WSDL does not offer us a way to do this as is.

Comment: Sorry for the spotty commenting / editing. I ran into a character limit in COMMENTS and just updated the original.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - Updated today.